# php regex - match only in between two factors

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a situation where I only need to alter HTML string when the following conditions are met:

- It has to be between a tags
- The href can't start with http:// or javascript:
- The href can't end with .html or .htm

Now the problem is, this has to be a global regex search in a big string, and it can find multiple solutions in one string.

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.be">Google</a>
<a href="javascript:node(133)">Go there</a>
```

should be ignored

```
<a href="testpage.html">Test</a>
<a href="testpage2.htm">Test page 2</a>
```

should also be ignored, but

```
<a href="file.mp3">File</a>
<a href="stuff.flv">Stuff</a>
```

should be caught.

I know doing regex with HTML is selling your soul to the devil, but I'm already too advanced in this parser and will take me too long to throw it around entirely.

So is there a way to check a string both at the start and at the end, not knowing if the string itself will be at the start or at the end (so usage of ^ or $ is pretty much impossible).

Comment: Why not do it with javascript after the page loads instead of serverside before the page is erved?

Comment: Because it's not to show on a page, it's to parse into an object. It's difficult to explain but there just is no client-side interaction with the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regexp that may help you.

```
<a href="(?!http:\/\/)(?!javascript:)[\w\s,/-]+(?!.html?)\.\w+">.+?<\/a>
```

I used negatives lookaheads to enforce your rules.

`(?!http:\/\/)` Will make sure the link doesn't start with `http://`. `(?!javascript:)` is similar for the javascript rule.

Then, it'll control the end of the path, and if it ends with htm, or html, the negative lookahead will make sure the string is not matched.

You may want to complete the `[\w\s,/-]` part, which matches the path and name of the file. I allow alphanumeric characaters, `-`, `,`, `/` and `_`, feel free to add what you need there.

Comment: `/` is not a special regex character (you only need to escape them if you use them as delimiters) but the `.` is, you need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this regex:

```
/<a href="(?!.*?http|javascript)(?!.*?html?)(?=.*?>)(.+?)<\/\w+>/
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mG8sZ9)

Comment: Also works, except that it takes everything until before the </a> tag

Comment: I'd rep you, but I don't have enough yet.

Comment: @Axon which part do you want to match?

Comment: Both what's between the " " from href, and between the ending > and </a>